# Making a table in HTML

Tags: html

What do you think should I do to make my code's output like in the photo?
Thank you for answering.

(I am typing any words in here because stackoverflow doesnt let me post this. This is the most detailed thing I can think of. I am new to the programming world and I have no one to assist me that's why I am asking for some help. Thank you for understanding.)
Here's my code:

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="20% " width="20%" cellspacing="0">

  <tr>
    <td rowspan="10"></td>
    <td colspan="9"></td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td rowspan="9"></td>
    <td colspan="8"></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="8"></td>
    <td colspan="7"></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="7"></td>
    <td colspan="6"></td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td rowspan="6"></td>
    <td colspan="5"></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="5"></td>
    <td colspan="4"></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="4"></td>
    <td colspan="3"></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="1"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td rowspan="0">
    </td>

  </tr>

</table>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhzX1.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make `table inside td`

```
<td rowspan="0" style="padding: 0; border: none;">
  <table border="1" cellpadding="10% " width="20%" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr><tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</td>
```

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="20% " width="20%" cellspacing="0">

  <tr>
    <td rowspan="10"></td>
    <td colspan="9"></td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td rowspan="9"></td>
    <td colspan="8"></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="8"></td>
    <td colspan="7"></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="7"></td>
    <td colspan="6"></td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td rowspan="6"></td>
    <td colspan="5"></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="5"></td>
    <td colspan="4"></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="4"></td>
    <td colspan="3"></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3"></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
    <td colspan="1"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td rowspan="0" style="padding: 0; border: none;">
      <table border="1" cellpadding="10% " width="20%" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>

  </tr>

</table>
```